# I want throw an alert after the user enters wrong password (the validation is from DB), I need to generate alert from my Servlet, how to do that?

Tags: java, servlets

After the user clicks "Ok" in the alert, it should redirect to same index.html page.
when I am using the below

```
pw.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
pw.println("alert('Wrong password');");  
pw.println("</script>");
```

the alert is getting popped out. But I want to redirect to same `Login html` page. And for that I am using

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

it is not redirecting to index.html page. PS after writing the dispatcher code there is no pop-up though it is redirecting to same index.html page. Please advise me on this.

Comment: can you please share some more code to understand the question and make sure that in Dispatcher pass full path of html file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing *client side* and *server side*. And you are trying to forward to a HTML page which is not allowed: you can only forward to a servlet running in the same servlet context as the originating one.

You must choose one:

- either server side: you put an alert indicator in a request attribute and forward to a servlet that will display the index page. In that servlet, you test the alert indicator and only display the alert if it is present, and normally display the other parts of the page
- either client side: you can use `window.location.assign` to ask the browser to request a new page:

  ```
  response.setContentType("text/html");  
  pw.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
  pw.println("alert('Wrong password');");  
  pw.println("window.location.assign('/path/to/index.html');");  
  pw.println("</script>");
  ```

  But you should send a conformant HTML page with a correct structure to avoid that a stricter browser refuse to interpret it.

Comment: Thank you so much Serge ! it really worked for me. Just one doubt, can you please help me to understand why in my case RequestDispatcher did not work?

Comment: RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
rd.include(request, response);
I tried to use include, and it too worked.